# IHttpAuthenticationFeature.Handler is null when

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

When I try to perform an HTTP/POST against `/connect/token` endpoint, I get a `NullReferenceException` with the following stack trace:

> at IdentityServer4.Hosting.AuthenticationHandler.AuthenticateAsync(AuthenticateContext
>   context) 
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.d__12.MoveNext()

Debugging into the IdentityServer4's source code I've found that this happens becuase `IHttpAuthenticationFeature` from `HttpContext.Features` is `null`, thus the code falls into the `if(auth == null)` case (see the source code [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/75ac815e744051d8150274743cdd8588eb68abb0/src/IdentityServer4/Hosting/AuthenticationHandler.cs)):

```
    IHttpAuthenticationFeature GetAuthentication()
    {
        var auth = _context.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpAuthenticationFeature>();
        if (auth == null)
        {
            auth = new HttpAuthenticationFeature();
            _context.HttpContext.Features.Set(auth);
        }
        return auth;
    }
```

My `Startup.ConfigureServices(...)` looks as follows:

```
services.AddTransient<IUserStore<IdentityUser>, CustomStore>
(
    provider => new CustomStore
    (
        Configuration["company:data:legacy:connectionString"]
    )
);

services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddUserManager<IdentityUserManager>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityConfig.GetApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityConfig.GetClients())
        .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>();
```

I can't figure out if I'm missing some service registration or configuration.

Answer (score 0):

looks like it can't find Cookie and OpenId Authentication handler on the client. make sure you have properly added above mentioned middleware configurations in your web client from where you are calling the endpoint.

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {

                AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies"
            });

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
    SignInScheme = "Cookies",

    Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

    ClientId = "mvc",
    ClientSecret = "secret",

    ResponseType = "code id_token",
    Scope = { "api1", "offline_access" },

    GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
    SaveTokens = true
});
```

**Update**  Keep in mind if you are asking for token (even if you are doing it through postman) you have to set up a client, pass client id and secret (depends on your client config) in your request with validated grant type and code that you got from previous authorization request. Check [this](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/endpoints/token.html#example)

Comment: Hey, but I'm using Postman to test `/connect/token`. And my clients won't be .NET Core-based.

Comment: And you are authorizing through postman as well? can you paste your post request??

Comment: I'm just trying to get at least a `401`. I assume that I should be able to send a request with no headers, and invalid credentials, and it should work anyway, am I mistaken?

Comment: Yeah! But, anyway, should I get a `NullReferenceException` when not passing the right headers and entity? This ends up with `HTTP/500` status :/